# how to fill report viewer field with count function using query?

Tags: asp.net, vb.net

I have a website with report viewer and I load a report to it pragmatically. I use this query

```
select receivedtime,status,count(*) from Outbox group by receivedtime,status
```

but when I run the website only `receivedtime`, `status` columns are filled with data, but `count(*)` is not??

How I can solve this problem?

Comment: Have you tried giving the count(*) an alias? Something like `select receivedtime,status,count(*) as num from Outbox group by receivedtime,status`

Answer (score 0):

I'm not too sure what `report viewer` actually means but how about given the result of `count(*)` an actual alias so that whatever report viewer you are using can refer to an actual "column name". I'm assuming that that query is a sql query and if you don't specify an alias where an aggregate function is used the output will return the data but with no column name. Try adding an alias to the query...

```
select receivedtime
       ,status
       ,count(*) as 'TotalItems' --alias this
from Outbox 
group by receivedtime,status
```

now, if the "report viewer" infers columns automatically then you shouldn't need to do anything else, or else refer to the result of `count(*)` as "TotalItems" when building databinding expressions

Comment: @user3859372 mate, what does "it does not work" mean? You are software developer...can you give more details other than "it does not work"? Thanks

Comment: I created a dataset with data table that has 3 columns (receivedtime, status and TotalCount)  and I created report.rdlc

Comment: I want to load a data to a reportviewer using that query.